# jQuery not able to update data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I am not able to update data attribute. I have a class `.edf` which when clicked adds new span tag to the clicked element in dom and updates data attribute `data-clck` **This is working**

Now I want that when I click on one of the newly added span element all `.edf`'s should have their data attribute `data-clck` updated to `0` value. **NOT WORKING**

Code below and [fiddle if required](https://jsfiddle.net/billupillu/14fgtx3v/):

```js
  var pans = "<span class='panok'></span><span class='panno'></span>";
  var input1 = "<input name='vendor_service_item' type='text' class='in_cell_input' value='";
  var input2 = "'>";
  var bal;
  $('.edf').click(function(){
    var dis = $(this);
    var clck = dis.attr('data-clck');
    if(clck == 0){
      $('.edf').each(function(){$(this).attr('data-clck','1');});
      bal = dis.html().toString();
      var nbal;
      if (bal.includes('$')){nbal = bal.replace('$','')}
      dis.html(input1+nbal+input2+pans);
      dis.attr('data-clck','2');
    }// if end
    else if(clck == 2){}
    else if(clck == 1){alert("Please deselect current cell to select other cells");}
  });

  $('.edf').on('click', '.panno', function(){
    var tis = $(this);
    tis.parent().html(bal);
    $('.edf').each(function(){$(this).attr('data-clck','0');});
  });//panno click end
```

```css
.edf{text-align:center;position:relative;}
.edf:hover{cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;}
  .panok{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background-color: #6dc777;
  }
  .panno{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background-color: #FF6666;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="tableizer-table" id="rebillable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Name</td>
      <td class="edf" data-avsid="b0sds00001" data-clck='0'>1</td>
      <td class="edf" data-avsid="bxsd000001" data-clck='0'>$10.22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What are we supposed to do when we run the snippet? If I click something, I get an input, but then I get stuck -- clicking the red and green blocks do nothing, and doing just about anything else tells me to "deselect". But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent *event propagation* - so what happens is that when you click on `panno` the event *propagates* to the *edf* which is also triggered.

One pointer - use `data('clck')` instead of `attr('data-clck')`. Also note `nbal` was not evaluating properly - fixed that too.

See demo below:

```js
var pans = "<span class='panok'></span><span class='panno'></span>";
var input1 = "<input name='vendor_service_item' type='text' class='in_cell_input' value='";
var input2 = "'>";
var bal;
$('.edf').click(function() {
  var dis = $(this);
  var clck = dis.data('clck');
  if (clck == 0) {
    $('.edf').each(function() {
      $(this).data('clck', '1');
    });
    bal = dis.html().toString();
    var nbal = bal.replace('$', ''); // CHANGED THIS
    /*if (bal.includes('$')) {
      nbal = bal.replace('$', '')
    }*/
    
    dis.html(input1 + nbal + input2 + pans);
    dis.data('clck', '2');
  } // if end
  else if (clck == 2) {} else if (clck == 1) {
    alert("Please deselect current cell to select other cells");
  }
});

$('.edf').on('click', '.panno', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // ADDED THIS
  var tis = $(this);
  tis.parent().html(bal);
  $('.edf').each(function() {
    $(this).data('clck', '0');
  });
}); //panno click end
```

```css
.edf {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.edf:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.panok {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #6dc777;
}

.panno {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #FF6666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableizer-table" id="rebillable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Name</td>
      <td class="edf" data-avsid="b0sds00001" data-clck='0'>1</td>
      <td class="edf" data-avsid="bxsd000001" data-clck='0'>$10.22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```